# creating a dic from a list of tuples where key takes a list of all available values in python3

Tags: python

this is my code:

```
mylist=[('joe',120),('john',160),('abraham',250),('soo',250)]

dic={}

for i in mylist:
    if i[1] in dic:
        dic[i[1]].append(i[0])
    else:
        dic[i[1]]=i[0]
print(dic)
```

I expect:

```
dic={'120':['joe'], '160':['john'], '250':['abraham','soo']}
```

but I get this error:

```
    dic[i[1]].append(i[0])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Your tuples contain names and *integers*, so your output dictionary is going to have integer keys, not strings. Do you have to have string keys? So `{120: ['joe'], 160: ['john'], 250: ['abraham', 'soo']}`, not `{'120': ['joe'], '160':['john'], '250': ['abraham', 'soo']}`

Answer (score 3):

When `i[1]` is not in the dictionary, you need to create a list object. Instead you are assigning just the string to that key:

```
dic[i[1]]=i[0]
```

If you wrap that in a list display your code works:

```
dic[i[1]] = [i[0]]  # a list with i[0] as the only element
```

You can make your code a lot more readable by using tuple unpacking:

```
for name, value in mylist:
    if value in dic:
        dic[value].append(name)
    else:
        dic[value] = [name]
```

If you used the [`dict.setdefault()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) you can do away with testing if the key is already there:

```
for name, value in mylist:
    dic.setdefault(value, []).append(name)
```

Here, `dict.setdefault()` will set the value to an empty list if the key is not yet present in the dictionary, so that the `.append()` call will always work.

Another alternative would be to use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict); this takes a factory that'll produce a new value for keys that are not there when you try to acces them; set the factory to `list` to get the same results:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(list)

for name, value in mylist:
    dic[value].append(name)
```